# watch multiple nodes on zookeeper with multithreaded system

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have a project which I watch several nodes in several different threads. Now, I noticed that when I watch a node, and it changed, and an event is raised, the watch on a certain node (called A for example) blocks all the other watchers. So only after the watcher on A is finished , the other watcher will return to watch the nodes changes. Meaning, if a node is changed (called B for example) while its watcher is blocked, only after the watcher on A is finished, the watcher on node B will raise the event.

This problem causes the application be slower.

So, in order to fix this, I wanted to use a different client connnection for each thread, (using curator), but I have read that one connection should be enough, and if I need more than one, there is something worng with my implementation.

1) I dont understand what is the problem with multiple connection to zookeeper server

2) Is there another solution for my problem?

**Edit - more specific about the problem**

I have a master which gets requests from clients ( and each clients can save files on my server and we do some process on this file, it is more complex than it sounds, i wont elaborate it), and the master creates a node in /tasks/ for a worker to process the file (without its data of course, the data is in a db). When the worker watches his node, he processes the file, and when he finishes, he creates a node in /status (which has all the files that their process were finished).
The master watches the node /status , and when something was changed , it gets the children, and creates a thread (in order to make all faster, because zookeeper watchers and callbacks are single threaded ), which will release those files (remove some meta from db, return a response to client, remove some variable etc.).

That is one of the main flows, but I have another important parts of the code which listen on nodes, and process their children when there are changes.

Because this thing is in a thread, I created a list of the nodes that were finished already, so I wont do the final process more than once, but it was more complex than that, and that solution caused other problems, some concurrency bugs.

So as i asked

1) What is the problem with multiple connection , for each important flow, so i wont have to create threades inside watches and callback?

2) Is there another solution i can use here?

Comment: if you can't figure out how to receive ZK events in parallel, you can just move all heavy code from listener to background processing

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I did that, but then I have several threads, on the same node children, and i need to synchronized them, with variables etc. , so a child wont be processed several times. And it makes the code much more complex and causes bugs. That is why i wanted to make a single connection for each watcher (i dont have alot of watchers..)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this besides creating a new ZK connection for each thread/watcher?

Answer (score 1):

It's not well documented, but ZooKeeper has a single thread for handling watchers and async callbacks. We wrote a tech note for Curator about it. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CURATOR/TN1

Comment: I am aware of this problem. I just want to know all my options to resolve this issue. I tried using threads inside the watchers, but it causes other problems. I wonder if using several connections to the zookeeper is a good solution?

Comment: If you describe what you're trying accomplish I might be able to help.

Comment: how exactly? How can I contact you?

Comment: Just describe it here

Comment: I have described it in the question. I have several watchers, in several threads, and I don't want to make the threads wait for one thread to finish his watching. And when I used threads inside the watchers, so they only have one line (creating the thread) and be faster, it causes other problems (because I need to manage those threads properly...).

Comment: can you help me with this problem? @Randgalt

Comment: You need to describe in detail what you're trying to accomplish and by that I mean what is the task you have to accomplish. All you've said is that you have have several watchers and you don't want to have them wait - for that only threading will solve the problem. But, if you describe your app in detail maybe we can help with a different solution.